# Django query with related models shows only fields of one model

Tags: django, django-select-related

I have three related models and want to make a query to get a combination of fields from  all three models.

```
invoice_select = Ordered_item.objects.filter(oi_order = o_id).select_related()
```

generates the SQL-statement which I can check with the debug_toolbar. The SQL statement contains all fields of the related models.

Sending the result of the query to a html-file with

```
 return render_to_response('invoice_select.html', {'invoice_select':invoice_select}
```

provides only the the expression which was defined for the Ordered_item model with:

```
   def __unicode__(self):
   return u'%s -- %s -- %s' % (self.oi_order, self.oi_pos, self.oi_item)
```

So the result of the query looks like:

```
{'invoice_select': [<Ordered_item: 1109231733 -- 01 -- BP-0516-aa>]}
```

which are exactly the fields defined in the def **unicode**(self):

What can I do to add more fields to the result of the query? Why do the fields in the SQL not show up in the result of the query ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How exactly are you outputting `invoice_select`?  If you are just putting `{{ invoice_select }}` in your view, Django is going to basically output:  `{{ invoice_select.__unicode__() }}`.  If you want to output more, or differently, you will need to edit your view.

Comment: Could you give me an example please how to access other fields

Answer (score 1):

You're just looking at the string representation of the object, which obviously uses the `__unicode__` method. The fields are there, of course, if you access the objects directly.

Comment: I have no idea how to access the fields of the related objects. Could you give me an example please ?

Answer (score 1):

The __unicode__ method is automagically being called when you refer to the object as a string. You could simply put the fields you care about in the __unicode__ method (assuming a Manufacturer model):

```
def __unicode__(self):
   return u'%s -- %s -- %s -- %s -- %s' % (self.oi_order, self.oi_pos, self.oi_item,
       self.manufacturer.name, self.manufacturer.favorite_stuffed_animal)
```

If you don't want to put that in the __unicode__ method, which does get used for other things, you can easily put it in some separate method and directly call that one rather than implicitly calling the __unicode__ one.

Also further note that if manufacturer might be null you need to handle that, perhaps with a try-catch block.

Here's what a separate method might look like:

```
def get_str(self):
    return u'%s %s' % (self.oi_order, self.manufacturer.name)
```

And then if you have an oi instantiated:

```
str = oi.get_str()
```

Comment: how could the separate method look like? could you give me an example?

Comment: Is it possible to generate in a view a second query on a different model and pass the result of two different queries with one return_to_response call over to the template ?

Comment: I'll update the entry with a simple method, but it should be pretty straightforward. I'm not sure exactly what you're asking with your second comment, that's probably worthy of a separate post.